# How can I create a button that links to another PHP page and still staying inside Facebook framework?

Tags: php, facebook

I am new both to PHP and new to Facebook...

I am trying to create a button that by clicking on it, the next page will be called ,

how can I do that and still remain in Facebook framework?

I tried using an HTML button with reference to next PHP page, but it took me out of Facebook framework...

and I need to use variables from the calling page.

can someone help me?

Thank!!

Comment: When the user click on the button, you want to send informations or change the page displayed??

Comment: Hi I would like to be able to change the page displayed, and to be able to use some vars from the calling page

Comment: Look at my answer below, I think it's what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, you should always use a "Dispatcher" in your top level directory, and hide your other classes in subfolders, with appropriate permissions.

Doing so, here is what you can do:

index.php (dispatcher)

```
<?php
switch($_GET['p']) {
 case 'home':
    include './include/home.php';
    break;
 case 'anotherPage':
    include './include/anotherPage.php';
    break;
 default:
   include './include/home.php'; 
   break;
}
?>
```

And now, all you have to do is to call your Facebook page like this (sorry, I don't remember the exact facebook url for application):

```
http://www.facebook.com/yourapp/?p=home
http://www.facebook.com/yourapp/?p=anotherPage
```

[EDIT]
If you want to send informations and get it back, modify your HTML form to POST data at the dispatcher like this:

```
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="./?p=anotherPage">
```

Than, modify the "anotherPage.php" to verify the POST data, process it and maybe set the data you want back in $_SESSION['myVariable']. Once everything is done, redirect the page to the initial one:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (ISSET($_POST['myData']) && $_POST['myData'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['myVariable'] = "HelloWorld";
}
header('Location: http://www.facebook.com/myApp/?p=home');
```

I hope this will help you with your project

Comment: Hi JPelletier, I am trying to implement your solution and with the dispatcher , I am getting the home page, which call a html file with a button, defined as: <form method=POST action="http://www.facebook.com/myapp/?p=filename"><input value="value" type="submit" /></form>.....but when clicking on that button, I am getting a "Sorry, your request could not be processed." from Facebook. can you please advise?

Comment: Also, try to set the `name` attribute of your form elements, I had a problem with that in the past. `<input name="submit" value="value" type="submit" />`